# How to get email address used to sign in AzureB2c with Microsoft Intra multi tenant custom flow

Tags: openid-connect

I'm trying to setup a custom policy to allow users to auhtenticate in Azure for multitenant Microsoft Entra.
I've followed this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and authentication works but i'm not able to get user's email in jwt token returned to the client.

Registered apps (IdentityExperienceFramework and ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework) are granted to read email property with graph

When user is created in AzureB2C from AAD account, properties email and orther emails are not populated.  Any clue how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to do it and see if it works out successfully.

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>commonaad</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OpenIdConnect">
      <Metadata>
        <!-- ... -->
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- ...other output -->
        <!-- Add OutputClaim -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```